# UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Tags: swift, alamofire, mailgun

Image trying to send emails from iOS with MailGun. I have set up a trial account for testing. I'm using this code for sending:

```
 let parameters = [
               "from": "my@mail.com",
               "to": "you@mail.com",
               "subject": "Hello from Swift",
               "text": "Mail sendt from MailGun"]
           let header : HTTPHeaders = [
               "Authorization": "myAPIKey",
               "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

           let url = "My URL"
           AF.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: parameters,
                      encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                      headers: header)
               .responseJSON { response in
                   print("Response: \(response)")
           }
```

This gives the error:

```
> Response:
> failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason:
> Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error:
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
> character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
> character 0.})))
```

Where is this going wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, Are you sure you have the right encoding? Is it suppose to be url encoding or JSON encoding

Comment: @valosip I tried to change from `encoding: URLEncoding.default` to `  encoding: JSONEncoding.default` With the same result